# Creating a folder with the current time as name

Tags: ruby, windows, directory, mkdir

I'm trying to write a simple backup script in Ruby that copies a folder to a specific directory with a timestamp in its name.
My code is (simplified):

```
require 'Fileutils.rb'
time = Time.now
FileUtils.cp_r "C:/somefolder", "D:/somefolder_backup_#{time}"
```

But I keep getting

```
`fu_mkdir': Unknown error - mkdir failed (SystemCallError)
```

The same happens if I simply want to create a folder with the current time in it:

```
FileUtils.mkdir "C:/somefolder_#{time}"
```

It doesn't seem to be a privileges issue, if I leave out the #{time}-thing it works perfectly.

Any advices are appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My guess is that there is a character in your time string that Windows doesn't allow in a directory name (your code works fine for me on my Ubuntu machine). Try formatting your time so that it's just numeric, and that'll probably work:

```
require 'Fileutils.rb'
time = Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
FileUtils.cp_r "C:/somefolder", "D:/somefolder_backup_#{time}"
```

Comment: Duh, so obvious. As rspeicher said, the colons where the problem. Thanks, your code works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

The string returned by `Time.now` has colons in it, which is an illegal character for directory names.

Use Daniel's code to format the time.